# Shopify variants added is being replaced in cart page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have added a shopify variant product into the cart,but after some time it changes to the default product. Two js files are showing in the console : Initially cart.js file shows,then change.js after that add.js . Then the cart page is reloaded automatically and shows the default variant. It replaces the variant i have selected.

Thank You

Comment: There is an app installed (Product options by bold) for additional product fields

Comment: Hi Sujeesh!  I work at Bold and can confidently recommend reaching out to our support team.  We'll be able to solve the problem through our support channels a lot faster than through a public forum like this :) 
Do you have any of the following apps installed:  Quantity Breaks, Bundles or Customer Pricing?  If you do, there could be a configuration or installation issue with one of those apps, and our support team can take a look and will usually clear those up pretty quickly.